# error in fork and usleep

Tags: c, fork, usleep

i write this code:
http://ideone.com/cNypUb

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void signchld (int signal){
    fprintf (stderr, "[X] child exited\n");
}


int main(){
    signal (SIGCHLD, signchld);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=300;i++){
        pid_t f;
        f=fork();
        if(f==0){
            //child
            usleep(3*1000000);
            fprintf (stderr, "[C1] %d\n",i);
            exit(0);
            fprintf (stderr, "[C2] %d\n",i);
        }else if(f>0){
            fprintf (stderr, "[P1] %d\n",i);
            usleep(20000000);
        fprintf (stderr, "[P2] %d\n",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the `[p2]` run each 3 second and then run next loop

I expect to see this output:

```
[P1] 0
[C1] 0
[X] child exited
```

after 20 second

```
[P2] 0
[P1] 1
[C1] 1
[X] child exited
```

Comment: Note that the `[C2]` print is never executed; the compiler should be warning you about 'unreachable code'. Strictly, you're not supposed to call `fprintf()` or a large number of other functions from inside a signal handler function.  Your `[P1]` and `[P2]` prints should occur roughly every two seconds.  The first `[C1]` message should be delayed for about 3 seconds, but thereafter, they should appear every 2 seconds or so.  You never `wait()` so you probably have an army of zombies before the program terminates after 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Argh; I miscounted the zeros in 20000000 (7 of them, not 6).  So your program runs for over an hour; the `[P1]` and `[P2]` messages should appear every 20 seconds, and the `[C1]` messages will also appear every 20 seconds or so.  The sleep in the parent process controls these rates (and I misread the question thinking that they were 2 second delays, not 20 second delays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the signal handler `signchld()` that interrupts `usleep()` in the parent, as we can prove by substituting

```
usleep(20000000);
```

with

```
if (usleep(20000000) < 0) {
    if (errno == EINTR)
        fprintf (stderr, "[PX] usleep() interrupted by a signal\n");
}
```

(and of course including `errno.h`).  This will print

```
[P1] 0
[C1] 0
[X] child exited
[PX] usleep() interrupted by a signal
[P2] 0
[P1] 1
```

and so on.

On my system (GNU/Linux) the man page for `usleep()` reads:

> 4.3BSD,  POSIX.1-2001.   POSIX.1-2001  declares this function obsolete; use nanosleep(2) instead.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of usleep().
>
> Only the EINVAL error return is documented by SUSv2 and POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: Good point. Linux documents EINTR; apparently, POSIX did not (`usleep()` is not part of POSIX 2008 or 2013 anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You see parent process waking up earlier than 20 seconds you've expected is because exiting child has delivered SIGCHLD signal which you've registered to handle. That signal wakes up `usleep()` prematurely. It returns -1 and has errno set to EINTR.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `usleep()`. It's certainly EINTR, as defined in the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

You need to add a `wait()` call in your SIGCHLD handler (http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

Note also that it is undefined which process gets run first after the `fork()`. Even though they are parent and child, they are scheduled independently by the operating system. Also, `usleep()` guarantees a sleep of no less than the number useconds passed to it, unless interrupted. It does **not** guarantee that the process will awaken at that time, though normally it will be pretty close.

Don't try to use `usleep()` or any of its variants for process synchronization. Use the proper IPC routines.

Answer (score 1):

usleep function can not take arguments with values more than 1,000,000
usleep(20000000) should certainly cause an unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Manpage USLEEP(3):
The type useconds_t is an unsigned integer type capable of holding integers in the range [0,1000000].